# How to create a merge table from a partitioned table and a unpartitioned table

Tags: mysql, merge, union

I have a partitioned table and an unpartitioned table in a mysql table. I will like to create a union merge table for the two tables. The problem is, after creating the merge table, I get this error when I try to access the table: `Unable to open underlying table which is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist`

When I run the check table command on it, I get the following errors(ptable is the partitioned table):

```
Table 'mydb.ptable' is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist
Unable to open underlying table which is differently defined or of non-MyISAM type or doesn't exist
Corrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure both the partitioned table and non-partitioned table are of MyISAM type? they should be. (Please make sure 'ptable' is of MyIsam type).

  Continue reading [here](http://magicallinux.blogspot.in/2012/07/on-mysql-merge-tables.html).

Comment: Yes, the both are. I already read that blog and run a "show create table " command on the tables to double check.

Answer (score 0):

From the MySQL docs u cannot have tables with partitions to be used in the MERGE storage engine

MERGE tables do not support partitioning. That is, you cannot partition a MERGE table, nor can any of a MERGE table's underlying MyISAM tables be partitioned.